# Decomposition analysis for data between zero and one

Tags: data-transformation, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I want to analyze latent components of data that has values between zero and one (including zero and one).

In detail, the data structure is n x m  and I'm looking to find the r underlying components.

So far I was considering a non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) (or a non-negative tensor factorization as the data is actually from a time-series, where n and be broken down into h x t of h observations per t time periods.)

Two Questions:

1. Is there, e.g., a NMF or other approach that is especially tailored for data between zero and one?
2. Are there transformations that I should apply before, e.g., using a NMF approach? My data is also considerably skewed towards zero.

Comment: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26353300/

Comment: Thank you John! In the paper, the authors denote their approach as variational Bayesian matrix factorization for bounded bupport bata and also as beta-gamma NMF (BG-NMF).

Comment: This package in R on git appears to perform the Beta-Gamma Non-negative Matrix Factorization: https://rdrr.io/github/JoshuaTian/EpiCluster/man/BGNMF.html